# Windows 2012 Service Shows as Degraded

Tags: windows, wmi, nagios

I wanted to ask does anyone know what the definition of a degraded service is?

I'm monitoring some systems using nagios and check_wmi_plus, it runs the following WMI query:

```
select name, displayname, Started, StartMode, State, Status FROM Win32_Service
```

The State comes back as running, but the Status as degraded for one particular service (an in house application that is known for crashing).

This status only seems to be mentioned in WMI so now I'm in a bit of a battle because from the front end everything seems fine but from the monitoring system we warn of the system being degraded, so any additional information on this problem and how to resolve it (other than just bouncing the service) would be great.

The most I've found is the service didn't close down correctly.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the check_wmi_plus [change log](http://www.edcint.co.nz/checkwmiplus/?q=Change%20Log) for 1.62 the following was added:

> Added some additional text when services were in a degraded state.
>   Previously they were listed/counted as being "bad" but the display
>   message was confusing as it still showed them as "running". Thanks to
>   Paul Jobb.

According to Mircosoft a service in a "degraded" state is as follows:

> "Service is working, but in a reduced state."